# DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN on Fedora 33 when connecting to a guest network

Tags: wifi, networkmanager, captive-portal

I'm in a place where the guest WiFi (the network itself has no login/password) is the only internet access. When I connect to it from Fedora 33 and using any browser (Chrome / Opera / Firefox) I can't connect to the network and receive the `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN` error page with the text:

```
This site can’t be reached

captiveportal-login.captive-2020.aio.cloudauth.net’s server IP address could not be found.

DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN
```

With Windows 10 there is no such issue, it just instantly raises the Chrome window with either `http://www.gstatic.com/generate_204` or `http://www.msftconnecttest.com/` address with later redirection to `http://captiveportal-login.captive-2020.aio.cloudauth.net/swarm.cgi` for accepting terms of use. And that's it, I'm connected.

How to fix this?

I found [suggestion](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/t/downgrade-from-33-to-32/9952/3) to disable `systemd-resolved.service` and remove `/etc/resolv.conf`, which didn't help:

```
sudo systemctl stop systemd-resolved.service
sudo systemctl disable systemd-resolved.service
sudo chattr -a -i /etc/resolv.conf
sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager.service
```

Both `resolvectl domain` and `resolvectl dns` return `Failed to get global data: Could not activate remote peer.` However, before removal `/etc/resolv.conf` it was different.

Please, help.

P.S. Temporaly bypassed it by connecting phone (Android) to Wi-Fi and using USB-tethering to Fedora.